# Getting lazy initialization exception using JCS Cache while retrieving one-to-many relation entities

Tags: jpa, jcs

We are using JCS Cache and successfully placed entities.  When we retrieve the data from JCS Cache, we are able to retrieve the entitiy but not able to retrieve the related entities if it has one-to-many relationship entities.  We are getting lazy initialization exption.  Please suggest us.

Answer (score 0):

Before putting the data into JCS Cache, retrieve the related entities.

Answer (score 0):

Using a non-ORM caching mechanism with entities requires care as it can easily lead to such problems. Essentially, you need to be certain that any object added to the Cache is initialized to the extent that some other process retrieving it from the cache requires.

I am not familiar but JCSCache but using Spring's caching abstraction as an example:

```
private CustomerService{
    @Cacheable
    public Customer loadCustomer(long id){

    /*if cache contains item with Key id this
     *is not called and therefore no session is 
     *open when the view is rendered.
     */
    customerDao.findById(id);  
    }
}
```

For example let's say you have a Customer with a collection of orders.

You have a process:

- display customer summary screen (name, address, etc).
- Customer entity is retrieved and added to the (non JPA) cache by some mechanism.
- as summary screen does not touch orders the collection is not initialized (assuming Lazy mapping)

You have process 2:

- display customer order history
- You call the same method as in [1] above to retrieve the Customer
- You are using OSIV pattern so without caching session remains opened and orders fetched on demand.
- However with caching, the cache manager detects that this Entity is cached and returns the partially initialized cached instance created in process [1].
- No session is ever opened and an exception will occur when you try to access the cached the lazy orders association.

So either you need to ensure cached instances are fully initialized, shift caching to the DAO tier where a session will be reopened or somehow intercept cache load events at the service layer and re-attach detached objects.